# Andorid device Keyboard is hiding the Text Field in a iframe

Tags: iframe, keyboard, focus, textfield

I am loaded a url using iframe in react.
Withing the iframe, the src being loaded has a text field. When trying to type in that TextField, the device keypad is hiding the Textfield.

If the same url is loaded without Iframe, it works fine, the Textfield always comes into the view.

````
<iframe
            title="Task Details Page"
            src="https://dev.storeintegrity.a-kmtkmg.net/products/details/details?exceptionId=1722"
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              border: 'none',
            }}
          ></iframe>```




Even on the src side (which is getting loaded within iframe) a added a focus event on the Text field

//notesInputRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
 //window.scrollTo(0, notesInputRef.current?.offsetTop ?? 0);  

tried both things
````

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `window.scrollTo()` to `top.scrollTo()`, as you need to run this on the parent page, not in the iFrame.